# C++ Programming Replacement for TCP transport protocol

Tags: c++, network-programming

I am interested in programming a replacement for the TCP protocol at the transport layer of network communications.  I still wish to use a standard/unaltered IP stack but want to layer my own replacement for TCP over it.

I am very familiar with network programming at the application layer.

What I would like to do is "install" my replacement on two windows machines that any call program designed to use TCP would use my replacement instead.

I would then test this by making a simple program between the two machines to connect a socket, send a message, and disconnect.  There should be no difference to the application side on if they are using standard TCP or my implementation.

I do understand that a computer installed with my implementation would not be able to communicate with a system that doesn't have it installed as my system would use my implementation and the other would use the "standard" protocol.

I understand I am not going to revolutionize network connectivity or better what many super smart people have done.  This is for personal education/edutainment purposes.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How would I go about replacing the TCP transport protocol on my windows machine with my own implementation so that an application on the system (with no modification) would have their traffic flow through my TCP layer and then back to the machines standard IP layer and so forth?  I have been reading about using raw sockets which handles part of the issues by allowing me to create my own headers over IP for a transport layer.  I just need a way to install this as the replacement for the machines TCP layer or at least have a way for the traffic to be redirected to my implementation.

Comment: The TCP protocol is implemented in the kernel. I don't think you can replace it, except if you tweak the kernel. With raw sockets you can indeed use your own transport layer, but that has nothing to do with replacing the existing implementation.

Comment: it looks like i may be able to effectively accomplish what I am trying to do using Windows Filtering Platform. [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571068(v=vs.85).aspx[/link].

Comment: So, what about Linux?

Comment: I have read and investigated that this is possible with linux.  I was just looking into the possibility with Windows and I cant really find a way.  I can use the Windows Filtering Platform to do packet inspections and such from all applications before it goes to the Windows TCP and IP layers, but I would like to replace those layers entirely while requiring no modification of a normal application but I just don't think it is possible.